# Equivalent of "in-laws" if we're just engaged

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I wonder how do you call your fiancée's family, basically, an equivalent of *in-laws* but for case we're not married yet. Is there any such a simple notion to describe this situation?

I'm looking for a usage like this:

> We'll spend a week looking after the [in-laws'] house and pets.

Comment: With changeable relationship terms, there are tense analogs. The hyphenated suffix _-to-be_ refers to future relations: _bride-to-be, brother-in-law-to-be, executor-to-be,_). And the hyphenated prefix _ex-_ refers to past relations: _ex-wife, ex-president, ex-mother-in-law_. A friend going through a divorce once told me that _ex-mother-in-law-to-be_ was her favorite English kinship term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### in-laws-to-be, [kinship term]-in-law-to-be

I agree with [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler):

> With changeable relationship terms, there are tense analogs. The hyphenated suffix *-to-be* refers to future relations: *bride-to-be, brother-in-law-to-be, executor-to-be,*). And the hyphenated prefix *ex-* refers to past relations: *ex-wife, ex-president, ex-mother-in-law*. A friend going through a divorce once told me that *ex-mother-in-law-to-be* was her favorite English kinship term.

"In law(s) to be" may seem like an awkward term, and it is, but it flourishes because there aren't many good alternatives. Some examples:

- > The in-laws-to-be may live in another town or another state, and the focus is often on the first flush of love and the excitement of planning a life together. — [In-Laws 101: 5 Questions to Ask Your Spouse-to-Be](https://www.foxnews.com/story/in-laws-101-5-questions-to-ask-your-spouse-to-be)
- > No, I didn’t say it and I don’t remember even thinking it when my son was born, although when I met my daughter-in law to be, something similar may have flitted around in my head. — [How to Be the Mother-in-Law You Always Wanted](https://www.nextavenue.org/how-to-be-mother-in-law-you-always-wanted/)
- > Do You Have to Ask Your Future Sister-in-Law to Be a Bridesmaid? — [The Best Gifts for Any Son-in-Law (And Any Occasion Too)](https://www.theknot.com/content/gifts-for-son-in-law)
- > What Can Cause a Mother-in-Law To Be Controlling? — [What To Do if Your Mother-in-Law Is Controlling](https://www.newsweek.com/controlling-mother-law-family-mil-marriage-advice-1707372)

Note: Hyphenation varies. For "in-laws-to-be" (the one not attached to another kinship term), usually it's fully hyphenated for clarity.

Comment: Ngram results for [future-in-laws vs laws-to-be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=future+in-laws%2Claws-to-be&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuture%20in%20-%20laws%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claws%20-%20to%20-%20be%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfuture%20in%20-%20laws%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claws%20-%20to%20-%20be%3B%2Cc0) (Google Ngram doesn't allow more than five "words"). Not even close.

Answer (score 6):

There is no special term; you can only call them *my future in-laws* or *Jane's/my fiancée's parents.*

Comment: How did you know she was called Jane?!

Answer (score 0):

We'll spend a week looking after the in-common-laws house and pets.

Comment: Do you have some supporting evidence for the use of "in-common-laws" as meaning a fiancée's family?